# How Function works in Excel when it uses Reference as Cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say in Sheet1, Cell "A1", There's a Current Date, and in Cell "A2" I'm typing the following formula

> ="Current Date is: "&Text(A1,"dd-mmmm-yy")

After a press enter, cell A2 will look like following (Obviously)

> Current Date is: 16-February-19

below is the screenshot

[image]

**Up to here is totally fine. Now yesterday, my friend asked me to make that Date String also a BOLD**

Yes Only that Date String, Not That "Current Date is: " part.

> So I told him, we have to create a UDF to make it BOLD, because in
>   Excel there isn't any Native Function for making font style BOLD.

So, I have developed a UDF with the following trick.

```
Function BOLD(ByVal TargetString As String)

    BOLD = "|" & TargetString & "|"

End Function
```

and here is the Worksheet_Change event programming

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim I As Variant
I = Target.Value

Dim A As Integer
Dim B As Integer

If Target.Count = 1 Then
    If VBA.InStr(1, I, "|") > 0 Then
        A = VBA.InStr(1, I, "|")
        B = VBA.InStrRev(I, "|")
        Target.Cells.Characters(A + 1, B - A - 1).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

> Now, with the above code, I'm only able to get the required result
>   when I'm NOT using a formula, But When I'm using a formula in a cell
>   it's not working. here is the screenshot.

[image]

Now my clear question is, we have seen both screenshots and formula is already mentioned there. But why in my case it's not responding?

Do Native Microsoft's Functions are coded with a different approach?

What is the correct way to develop this BOLD function so I can get the required Result?

I have tried earlier methods but it changes the cell formula which will not become the dynamic more.

Please guide. and also let me know if my explanation is not understandable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, formatting individual characters in a cell can only be done for text strings; not for formula results.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: Exactly what I felt after a lot of trials, But to make it confirmed, I have posted this query here. Let's wait for more comments to agree with your statement. Thank you.

Comment: I think that @RonRosenfeld is 100% correct, for reasons that make sense: you can only have one value in a cell, and trying to have both a formula and formatting information for a certain "run" of that formula is trying to sneak two values into a cell. The standard way to work-around limitations on what you can do with a formula or UDF is to move the functionality into a `WorkSheet_Change` event. In your case the worksheet_change would have to include both the functionality of the original formula and the formatting of the result.